# How to create common method with switch statement for different input types

Tags: java, generics, switch-statement, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor my code, because methods I created are very similar. Even intelliJ emphasises it. Aim of methods is to map (using switch statements) type 'MessageType' to also 'MessageType', which is from different package. The problem is that input types for switch statement are also from different packages.

```
private MessageType convertToInsurancePolisyMessageType1 (pl.different.MessageType messageType) {
    switch (messageType) {
        case WARN: return MessageType.WARN;
        case INFO: return MessageType.INFO;
        case ERROR: return MessageType.ERROR;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(messageType.name());
    }
}

private MessageType convertToInsurancePolisyMessageType2 (com.other.MessageType messageType) {
    switch (messageType) {
        case WARNING: return MessageType.WARN;
        case INFO: return MessageType.INFO;
        case ERROR: return MessageType.ERROR;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(messageType.name());
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to refactor this? Or should I leave like this?

Comment: First, don't do a case statement. Create a map instead. Second, if you use the two packages in the same source, you'll have to use fully qualified names for one of them.

Comment: I use even three packages with the same name 'MessageType'. Two of them are with fully qualified name in source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no work around to have some sort of listing/mapping between values of each of the input MessageType and the returned one.

Perhaps you could try to do some reflection based approach considering that names are very similar... however I think that would bring nothing but problems down the road if such names change and it has a performance hit if you are doing this transformation often.

To complement other answers based on static maps, which are quite fine btw, if you have control on the code return `MessageType` enum (i.e. you are developing such enum) I think that you should consider to encapsulate the conversion within that enum by overloading the same name for each type of argument.

There are several option here... I personally prefer `of` for the name. `valueOf` is acceptable but since valueOf(String) would throw an NoSuchElementException you should  keep that behavior. Let's stick to `of` here:

```
enum MessageType {
  WARN, INFO, ERROR;

  private static Map<pl.different.MessageType, MessageType> byPlDiffMType = 
      new EnumMap<>(Map.of(
          pl.different.MessageType.WARN, WARN,
          pl.different.MessageType.INFO, INFO,
          pl.different.MessageType.ERROR, ERROR
      ));

  private static Map<com.other.MessageType, MessageType> byCOthMType = 
      new EnumMap<>(Map.of(
          com.other.MessageType.WARNING, WARN,
          com.other.MessageType.INFO, INFO,
          com.other.MessageType.ERROR, ERROR
      ));

  public static MessageType of(pl.different.MessageType value) {
      return of(byPlDiffMType, value);
  }

  public static MessageType of(com.other.MessageType value) {
      return of(byCOthMType, value);
  }

  private static <V> MessageType of(Map<V, MessageType> map, V value) {
     final MessageType result = map.get(value);
     if (result == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     } else {
         return result;
     }
  }
}
```

Even if you dont have control on that class source you probably better of performance wise using `EnumMap` rather than regular `Map`s (e.g. `HashMap`).

I know that you are not saving much code though ... but I think that conversion into a enum make sense to be encapsulated in the enum class itself if you are developing it.

The only way to reduce line is to do some kind of matching thru the common names adding `if`s for those that are different but I would not encourage to do that as it would break silently with changes down the road and is probrably less "performy".

Comment: Thank you everyone for help :) I think your answer is the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after all I don't see nothing bad with your switch approach:)

Just to throw some alternative you can use maps:

```
public class MessageTypeConverter {
    private static final Map<pl.different.MessageType, com.other.MessageType> DIRECT_MAPPING = 
        new EnumMap<pl.different.MessageType, com.other.MessageType>(pl.different.MessageType.class) {{
            put(pl.different.MessageType.WARN, com.other.MessageType.WARN);
            put(pl.different.MessageType.INFO, com.other.MessageType.INFO);
            put(pl.different.MessageType.ERROR, com.other.MessageType.ERROR);
        }}; 
    private static final Map<com.other.MessageType, pl.different.MessageType> REVERSE_MAPPING =
        new EnumMap<com.other.MessageType, pl.different.MessageType>(com.other.MessageType.class) {{
            put(com.other.MessageType.WARN, pl.different.MessageType.WARN);
            put(com.other.MessageType.INFO, pl.different.MessageType.INFO);
            put(com.other.MessageType.ERROR, pl.different.MessageType.ERROR);      
        }};

    private com.other.MessageType convertToInsurancePolisyMessageType1(pl.different.MessageType messageType) {
        return DIRECT_MAPPING.computeIfAbsent(messageType, key -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(messageType.name()));
    }

    private pl.different.MessageType convertToInsurancePolisyMessageType2(com.other.MessageType messageType) {
        return REVERSE_MAPPING.computeIfAbsent(messageType, key -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(messageType.name()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why both of you are using a `HashMap` rather than an `EnumMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (with credit to RealSkeptic - sorry your comment appeared after I started writing this, but the same thing!):

```
public class DifferentMessageTypeConverter {
    public enum DifferentMessageType {
        WARNING, INFO, ERROR;
    }

    public enum InsurancePolicyMessageType {
        WARN, INFO, ERROR;
    }

    private static final Map<DifferentMessageType, InsurancePolicyMessageType> DIFF_TO_INS_MAPPING;

    static {
        DIFF_TO_INS_MAPPING = new HashMap<>();
        DIFF_TO_INS_MAPPING.put(DifferentMessageType.WARNING, InsurancePolicyMessageType.WARN);
        DIFF_TO_INS_MAPPING.put(DifferentMessageType.INFO, InsurancePolicyMessageType.INFO);
        DIFF_TO_INS_MAPPING.put(DifferentMessageType.ERROR, InsurancePolicyMessageType.ERROR);
    }

    public InsurancePolicyMessageType convertToInsurancePolisyMessageType1(DifferentMessageType dmt) {
        dmt = Optional.ofNullable(dmt)
                      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("dmt must not be null"));

        return Optional.ofNullable(dmt)
                       .map(DIFF_TO_INS_MAPPING::get)
                       .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(messageType.name()));
    }
}
```